# Різниця між "слідкувати", "стежити" й "пильнувати"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми

У метро звернула увагу на фразу: "Шановні пасажири! **Слідкуйте** за своїми дітьми на ескалаторі".

Подумалось, що в цьому контексті доречнішим було б "**пильнуйте**".

Проте, заглянувши у **Словник української мови**, я ще більше заплуталась, бо слова ***`слідкувати`***, ***`пильнувати`*** й ***`стежити`***, як виявилось, дуже близькі за значенням.

[СЛІДКУВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/slidkuvaty)

[ПИЛЬНУВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pyljnuvaty)

[СТЕ́ЖИТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/stezhyty)

Стаття на ресурсі [Gazeta.ua](https://gazeta.ua/articles/ukraine-newspaper/_slidkuvati-stezhiti-chi-pilnuvati/521653), автор - [Олександр СТУКАЛО](http://redactor.in.ua/ru/interview/5582.Oleksandr_Stukalo_U_kozhnomu_vidavnitstv%D1%96_%E2%80%93_svo%D1%97_pravila_ukra%D1%97nsko%D1%97_movi), теж не зазначає про чітке розмежування у використанні цих слів.

> Від знавців мови часом можна почути, що "`слідкувати`" вживається,
>   коли йдеться про вимову, одяг, щось неживе, а "`стежити`" — коли про
>   людей.
>
> Академічний тлумачний словник української мови подає п'ять
>   контекстуальних значень слова "`слідкувати`": 1) дивитися на те, що
>   переміщується; 2) наглядати за чим-небудь; 3) стежити за чимось або
>   кимось переважно з метою викриття; 4) уважно стежити за розвитком
>   чогось. І останнє: 5) іти, ходити за кимось слідом — без мети
>   стеження. Наприклад, у Марка Вовчка: "Ми й слідком за нею слідкували,
>   — іде вона, оглядається, а загледівши, що її доганяють, побіжить". Як
>   бачимо, слова "`стежити`" і "`слідкувати`" — синоніми. А п'яте
>   значення, у якому це слово зараз вживають досить рідко, теж має право
>   на існування.
>
> Крім "`стежити`" та "`слідкувати`", є ще в українські мові
>   "`пильнувати`". Загалом це слово чимось подібне за значенням до
>   попередніх двох, але має й відмінності. Одне з тлумачень — таки
>   "слідкувати за чим-небудь чи ким-небудь": Івасик пильнував за
>   Марічкою, щоби та не загубилася в бадиллі. І ще два значення:
>
> 1) бути на сторожі, захищаючи когось від нападів: Ми пильнували, щоби
>   здалеку не набігли хлопці й не потовкли нам носи;
>
> 2) виявляти ретельність у роботі, аби щось добре виконати: Я завжди
>   пильнував, пишучи прописи, щоб у мене було не так, як у сусідки, бо
>   сусідка мені не подобалася.

Тож чи є якесь притомне, але водночас просте пояснення, коли ці синоніми взаємозамінні, а коли ні?

Comment: А є ще *доглядати* і *наглядати*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Борис Рогоза](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), газета [”Хрещатик”:](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/111.htm)

> **Стежити** — багатозначне слово: **стежити за грою**, **стежити за успіхами учнів**, **стежити за розвитком подій**, **стежити за повідомленнями**, **стежити за собою**, **стежити, щоб ніхто не відстав тощо**. Похідні: **стеження**, **обстежити**, **обстеження**, **простежувати** і под.
>
> Дієслово **слідкувати** в значенні “стежити” в літературній мові вживається зрідка. Воно має інший зміст: “іти, ходити слідом за кимсь, чимсь”.
>
> [Марко Вовчок:](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BA)
>
> > “Ми слідком за нею **слідкували** — іде вона, оглядається, а загледівши, що її доганяють, побіжить”.

---

Отже, якщо брати точні поняття з СУМ, що ви тут навели, то можемо дещо знайти спільне.

**Стежити** — доволі широке поняття. Можна сказати навіть, що у звичному стані, тобто коли не тре чогось підкреслювати, охоплює всі значення.

> 1. Пильно спостерігати за ким-, чим-небудь, не відриваючи очей,
>      погляду.
> 2. З інтересом та увагою спостерігати за зміною, розвитком,
>      станом чого-небудь.
> 3. Здійснювати контроль, нагляд і т. ін. за ким-, чим-небудь; піклуватися, дбати про когось, щось.
> 4. Установлювати постійний нагляд, щоб впіймати кого-небудь або викрити, звинуватити в чомусь.
> 5. Відшукувати по сліду; висліджувати.

**Слідкувати** — майже все що стосується [будь-яких] змін: переміщення та [збереження] стану. Зміни я помітив курсивом.

> 1. Дивитися на те, що *переміщується, рухається*; стежити.
> 2. Наглядати за чим-небудь для *контролю*, *забезпечення порядку* і т. ін.
> 3. Стежити за ким-, чим-небудь перев. з метою *викрити, піймати* і т. ін.
> 4. Уважно стежити за *розвитком, зміною, станом* чогось.
> 5. *Іти*, *ходити слідом* за ким-небудь.

**Пильнувати** — якщо тре підкреслити важливість чи обов'язковість самого чи до якогось процесу [до чогось, когось].

> 1. Бути на сторожі, захищаючи кого-, що-небудь від нападів, ворожих дій і т. ін.
> 2. Стежити, слідкувати за ким-, чим-небудь.
> 3. Виявляти ретельність у праці, намагаючись виконати що-небудь добре, доброякісно.
> 4. Не спати, чергуючи, чатуючи біля кого-, чого-небудь.